# Web API controller for ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have designed a web application somehow similar to facebook. After login it displays data from 4 different models: **Identity Model** , **Community Model** , **Forms Model** and **FormCommunity Model** that is actually a relationship table. For this purpose I have designed a ViewModel named **CommunityUserViewModel**. Here is my **CommunityUserViewModel** code.

```
namespace FYP.ViewModel
{
    public class CommunityUserViewModel
    {
        public IList<Community> Com  { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser appuser { get; set; }
        public IList<FormCommunity> fcom { get; set; }

        public IList<QForm> qf { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now I am creating a Xamarin mobile app for this application using Web APIs. Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UToBKlnig4M&index=1&list=PLpbcUe4chE78YvgIMtmgNEmRGyGJcsQdF), I have generated an authentication Token. And now at duration 20:30, I am creating a new controller of type **Web API 2 Controller with actions using Entity Framework** using my discussed view model as I need to play data from these multiple tables after login. On creating this new controller I am getting error as displayed in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoaQn.png). The error stated that:

**There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'FYP.ViewModel.CommunityUserViewModel. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation.
CommunityUserViewModel:: Entity type CommunityUserViewModel has no key defined.Define the key for this entity type.
IdentityUserLogin:: Entity type IdentityUserLogin has no key defined.Define the key for this entity type.
CommunityUserViewModel: Entity Type: EntitySet 
CommunityUserViewModel that has no keys defined.**

Sharing code of 2 out of 4 models that have been used in **CommunityUserViewModel**.

**Community.cs**

```
    public class Community{
   [Key]
    public int CommunityID { get; set; }

    public string CommunityName { get; set; }
    public string CommunityDomain { get; set; }
    public string CommunityAbout { get; set; }
    public string CommunityLogo { get; set; }
    public int PrivacyID { get; set; }
    public string CommunityAdmin { get; set; }

    public virtual  ICollection<CommunityUser> CommunityUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FormCommunity> FormsCommunity { get; set; }   

    public Community(){
        FormsCommunity = new Collection<FormCommunity>();
        CommunityUsers = new Collection<CommunityUser>();
        }
}
```

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserRole { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: please do NOT post errors as images.  Take the time to copy down the error text and paste it into your post.

Comment: error has been updated